# how to loop the exception until the user successful or error

Tags: java, recursion

I'm using the code below to sign-in the user using email and password, but I'm not that advanced in java. I'm trying to loop the task exception until the user get successful.

```
  public void userLogin() {
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return ;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return ;
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Login Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    performTask();

                }
            });

}

public void performTask() {

    Task task = onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task);


    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        finish();
        userVerified();
    } else {
        String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();

        switch (errorCode) {

            case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The email address is badly formatted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etEmail.setError("The email address is badly formatted.");
                etEmail.requestFocus();
                break;

            case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The password is invalid ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etPassword.setError("password is incorrect ");
                etPassword.requestFocus();
                etPassword.setText("");
                break;

            case "ERROR_USER_MISMATCH":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The email address is already in use by another account.   ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etEmail.setError("The email address is already in use by another account.");
                etEmail.requestFocus();
                break;
            case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Your account not registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        performTask();
    }
}
```

When I try this loop the application will stop. i try to make the app will not crash. and the i don't know what i want to put in Task task = getTask();

Comment: because you add finish() this function will destroy the activity

Comment: but the user not successful and will not run in task.isSuccesful()

Comment: @indralesmana still crash after i delete finish();

Comment: why are you not writing the code in button clicklistener ? then you won't need a loop.

Comment: oh ya sorry i'm beginner. Thanks a lot

Comment: do upvote the comment if it is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe recursion will be a good solution for your problem as below. Assuming that you are getting `task` from some API (lets `getTaskDetails();`). Then each time you get error, display error using existing switch case and then again call the method `performTask()` to perform the task again and execute same logic until correct details are not received or task is not successful.

```
    public void userLogin() {
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return ;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return ;
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Login Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    performTask(task);

                }
            });

}

public void performTask(Task<AuthResult> task) {



    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        finish();
        userVerified();
    } else {
        String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();

        switch (errorCode) {

            case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The email address is badly formatted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etEmail.setError("The email address is badly formatted.");
                etEmail.requestFocus();
                break;

            case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The password is invalid ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etPassword.setError("password is incorrect ");
                etPassword.requestFocus();
                etPassword.setText("");
                break;

            case "ERROR_USER_MISMATCH":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The email address is already in use by another account.   ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etEmail.setError("The email address is already in use by another account.");
                etEmail.requestFocus();
                break;
            case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Your account not registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        userLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: but in getTaskDetail(); what they do ?

Comment: In your code there is a object variable named as task. As I don't know from where you are getting it, so getTaskDetails() is a dummy method. Which will replace with the actual code from where you are getting task value in your existing code.

Comment: ohh okay i'll try first.

Comment: The Task task = userlogin(); be error incompatible types.

Comment: Sorry I didn't you. Please elaborate.

Comment: okay i edit my question first . And you can answer my question.

Comment: you can check what i mean on my question, already edited the code

Comment: You can not call onComplete directly as well as you need to pass task as parameter to performTask method. So in else you would need to call userLogin method rather than the performTask.

Comment: I have updated the code in answer as per your updated code in question, Please check.

Comment: This is a reference code, you might need some changes as per your application.

Comment: It's run but try input error password for second time still crash and not read in user login again